# Logout in Blazor ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, logout, mudblazor

Create Logout Button in Blazor server side

I've tried to create a logout button in Blazor server side by clearing the cookies (`CookieAuthenticationDefaults`).

I will provide simple solution for this problem.

I use Mudblazor as frontend framework

Comment: _"I 've tried to create Logout button in blazor server side by clear Cookies"_ - so did it work or not?

Comment: Yes, it worked  I've Pasted the code

Answer (score 0):

Add for Program.cs

```
'builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddCookie(options =>
   {
       options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/0";
       options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
       options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
       options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
       options.LoginPath = "/Login";
       options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
       options.SlidingExpiration = true;
   });'
```

your logout button or item in dropdown list

```
`<MudMenuItem @onclick="Logout"><MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Logout" Title="Logout" Style="position: relative; left:5px; " />Logout</MudMenuItem>`
```

logout component

```
'   @page "/logout"
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
    @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
    @inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
    @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
    @code {
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {       
                await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.location.reload");      
        }
    }'
```